# how to pass value and name in label. text with format

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, uilabel

i have some label which will show the json value to that label. but i want to pass value with some text.here my `label.text`

```
 label1.text = [dict valueForKey:@"people1"];
```

`"people1"` is on data of my json.when i pass that `"people1"` value alone its working well. but i need to do some thing like this

for example my `"people1"` value is 20.it should like this:

```
  50 of the mad people
```

what format should i use in label1.text to get like above format in screen.Please help me pot.thanks!

```
        NSArray *jsonObject;
    jsonObject = @[@{@"Id1":@"mad",
                     @"people1":@"12",@"total1":@"20"},
                   @{@"Id2":@"normal",
                     @"people2":@"13",@"total2":@"30"}];

  NSError *err;
    NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:jsonObject options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:nil];



     NSArray *jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error: &err];



    NSDictionary *dict = [jsonArray objectAtIndex:0];
```

Comment: look into stringWithFormat

Comment: Don't use `valueForKey:` unless you are knowingly using KVC. Use `objectForKey:` to get a value from a dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString * variable = @"here";
NSString * str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"additional text %@",variable];
NSLog(@"%@", str);
```

Will result in:

> additional text here

Comment: i am having json data . i did all code. but dont know how to do that with string and to format that data

Comment: `NSArray *jsonObject;
    jsonObject = @[@{@"Id1":@"mad",
                     @"people1":@"12",@"total1":@"20"},
                   @{@"Id2":@"normal",
                     @"people2":@"13",@"total2":@"30"}];
    
  NSError *err;
    NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:jsonObject options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:nil];
    
    
    
     NSArray *jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error: &err];
    
    

    NSDictionary *dict = [jsonArray objectAtIndex:0];`

Comment: this is my full data code. i.e i am getting peopel valu and pass that to label.but dont know how to convert to string and too pass. i am new bie. please help me

Comment: @stepanferous Don't post a bunch of code in comments. Update your question with relevant details.